# Not displaying texts in print dialog in CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

As shown in the image below, the print dialog in the CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser of my WinForm project does not display its original texts.
[image: Not displaying texts in print dialog in CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser]
I tried many methods but none of them worked.

Obviously, it should be like this picture:
[image: Correct Print Dialog]

My initialize settings:

```
_Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty);

_Browser.ActivateBrowserOnCreation = true;
_Browser.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
_Browser.Name = "_Browser";
_Browser.TabIndex = 1;
_Browser.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip ?? DefaultContextMenuStrip;
_Browser.ContextMenuStrip.AutoClose = true;
_Browser.DownloadHandler = new SimpleDownloadHandler(this);
_Browser.LifeSpanHandler = new SimpleLifeSpanHandler(this);
_Browser.MenuHandler = new ContextMenuStripHandler(_Browser.ContextMenuStrip);
_Browser.AddressChanged += new System.EventHandler<CefSharp.AddressChangedEventArgs>(Browser_AddressChanged);
_Browser.FrameLoadStart += new System.EventHandler<CefSharp.FrameLoadStartEventArgs>(Browser_FrameLoadStart);
_Browser.FrameLoadEnd += new System.EventHandler<CefSharp.FrameLoadEndEventArgs>(Browser_FrameLoadEnd);
_Browser.LoadingStateChanged += new System.EventHandler<CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs>(Browser_LoadingStateChanged);
_Browser.ConsoleMessage += new System.EventHandler<CefSharp.ConsoleMessageEventArgs>(Browser_ConsoleMessage);
_Browser.StatusMessage += new System.EventHandler<CefSharp.StatusMessageEventArgs>(Browser_StatusMessage);
_Browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += new System.EventHandler(Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged);
_Browser.TitleChanged += Browser_TitleChanged;
try { Parent.ContextMenuStrip = _Browser.ContextMenuStrip; } catch { }
try
{
    var bs = _Browser.BrowserSettings?? new CefSharp.BrowserSettings(!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached);
    bs.Javascript = CefState.Enabled;
    bs.JavascriptAccessClipboard = CefState.Enabled;
    bs.JavascriptDomPaste = CefState.Enabled;
    bs.JavascriptCloseWindows = CefState.Enabled;
    bs.WebGl = CefState.Enabled;
    bs.Plugins = CefState.Enabled;
    bs.BackgroundColor = (uint)Color.FromArgb(255, BackColor).ToArgb();
    _Browser.BrowserSettings = bs;
}
catch { }

this.Controls.Add(_Browser);
_Browser.BringToFront();
```

It's some sample records of the `debug.log` file logs for just one time running the project:

```
[1125/121409.766:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(406)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[1125/121409.785:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(534)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[1125/121413.896:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(406)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[1125/121413.896:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(534)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[1125/121415.403:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
[1125/121415.403:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
....
[1125/121417.391:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(782)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglCreateContext: Requested GLES version is not supported.
[1125/121417.391:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(286)] eglCreateContext failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
[1125/121420.711:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(406)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[1125/121420.711:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(534)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[1125/121430.582:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(406)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[1125/121430.583:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(534)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[1125/121435.368:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(406)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[1125/121435.368:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(534)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[1125/121435.921:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
...
[1125/121500.833:ERROR:alloy_content_client.cc(117)] No localized string available for id 6738
[1125/121500.845:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
...
[1125/121507.834:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
[1125/121507.835:ERROR:alloy_content_client.cc(117)] No localized string available for id 6549
[1125/121507.835:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
[1125/121507.835:ERROR:alloy_content_client.cc(117)] No localized string available for id 6550
[1125/121507.835:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
...
[1125/121507.934:ERROR:alloy_content_client.cc(117)] No localized string available for id 6540
[1125/121507.934:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
[1125/121507.934:ERROR:alloy_content_client.cc(117)] No localized string available for id 6493
[1125/121507.946:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
[1125/121507.946:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
....
[1125/121507.966:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(406)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[1125/121507.966:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(534)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[1125/121508.101:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
[1125/121508.102:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
...
[1125/121510.580:ERROR:browser_info_manager.cc(547)] Timeout of new browser info response for frame 30064771073 [7,1]
[1125/121510.829:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
[1125/121510.831:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
...
[1125/121518.331:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(406)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[1125/121518.332:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(534)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[1125/121518.758:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
[1125/121518.762:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1059)] locale resources are not loaded
...
[1125/121524.142:ERROR:shared_buffer_dispatcher.cc(192)] Invalid serialized shared buffer dispatcher (invalid num_bytes?)
[1125/121524.142:ERROR:shared_buffer_dispatcher.cc(192)] Invalid serialized shared buffer dispatcher (invalid num_bytes?)
```

Comment: What version are you using? Operating system? What have you tried exactly? Please detail everything you've tried so far. Check the log file for errors see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: Thanks for the link, even though there was no solution there, it made me attach the log file ad more details to the post. I am using the latest version of CefSharp.WinForms (107.1.90) and its print dialog has no difference in win 7,8,10 that I tried.

Comment: Looks like an issue with UI fonts. Either a font color is grey in the dark theme, or more likely the print dialog is localized and the chosen font does not have localized glyphs.

Comment: The strings/resources come from the pak file. The locales folder needs to be distributed with your application. Are you seeing the error when running under visual studio?

Comment: Quick check with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample when I enable print preview everything looks as expected.

Comment: Thank you all, my problem is solved: of course, I did not understand where the problem came from. But when I updated CefSharp and copied the required files in the folder again, I saw that the problem was solved.